# Dialogflow custom entities not working as expected when created using dialogflow console - DeconstructingChatbots tutorial

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am following Priyanka Vergadia dialogflow tutorial on [Understanding Entities in Dialogflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmMRW3kG738&list=PLIivdWyY5sqK5SM34zbkitWLOV-b3V40B&index=6) and followed steps as she mentioned in the video. But for some reason my @AppointmentType custom entity isn't working as expected.

Here is how define my AppointmentType entity.

[image: AppointmentType entity]

Below is one of my training phrases and dialogflow detecting it as custom entity. I made it compulsory using slot filling.

[image: Training phrases]

Now when I add $AppointmentType in my response, upon testing it get stuck on the @AppointmentType question and kept asking the same question for appointment type. Also if I remove it from slot filling, it doesn't give any response even after getting all the slot inputs.

I searched the web stackoverflow, github, google issue tracker and others but no luck.

Comment: There's nothing obvious from what you're showing about what the problem could be, but that seems rather odd. Can you update the question to include examples (both text and screen shots0 of the dialog you're using and how Dialogflow is responding?

Comment: I made it work though, I deleted the existing agent and created a new one. Also instead of rushing through the whole creation in one go, I tested it at every step i.e. after each new intent or entity. One thing I noticed is that, I might not be waiting for agent training to be finished before testing it as it was taking some time to train.